# How exactly do I package latest dev snapshot of Commons locally?

Tags: 7, version-control, drush

I am trying to build up-to-date instance of Drupal Commons 7.x-3.x-dev. Release notes say to use command: "drush make build-commons-dev.make". I am totally new to drush and am trying to follow that instruction.

Can anyone provide more detailed instructions? That is my basic question.

Thanks, and more details below:

I thought I had figured it out. I can now go to root folder of site and run "drush profiles/commons/build-commons-dev.make" and I get what appears to be current Drupal Commons 7.x.-3.x-dev. However, as I test my instance, I am reporting bugs that Drupal coders say are already fixed and committed to github. So it seems that I am not properly synched.

Maybe I have wrong makefile? I got it from http://drupalcode.org/project/commons.git/tree/1228f4b

When I run "drush update" it says I am using all sorts of dev modules and that my site is 100% current. But I am clearly not current, because I am finding bugs that have already been fixed. Thanks for your help so I can test and contribute to Drupal Commons.

Answer (score 1):

I eventually got the answer straight from ezra-g at Acquia. From a unix-like console you can execute these commands (make sure you have drush and git installed locally):

1. cd ~
2. git clone --branch 7.x-3.x http://git.drupal.org/project/commons.git ./commons-profile
3. cd public_html
4. drush make ../commons-profile/build-commons-dev.make --prepare-install my_Drupal_Commons_site